# Locally sourcing Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Extreme beginner here guys so please explain as easily as possible. 
I've read multiple variations of this and still am unable to figure it out, any help is greatly appreciated.

What I am wanting is a local environment to be able to learn HTML & javascript, but cannot get the script source inside HTML to correctly reference the .js file sitting in the exact same folder as the .html file. 
I am testing in a Chrome browser just referencing the .html file on my local machine via file:///C:/JavaScript/Index.html.

2 files(index.html and JS.js), both located locally on C:\Javascript

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Title in browser tab</title>
</head>
<body>
"Text on the page"
<script src="C:\JavaScript\JS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

-Based on what I read, if they are in the same folder I should be able to just reference `<Script src="JS.js">` as there is no folder structure to look through, is that correct?

-I've also tried to absolute path via `<script src="file:///C:/JavaScript/JS.js">` and related versions of `<Script src="C:\Javascript\JS.js">` that do not work either.

In my JS.js file, I have nothing but `alert();` to test functionality, as my reasoning for incorrect sourcing. 
If I simply write `<script>alert();</script>` without referencing any outside source, the alert works as planned.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Start using debug tools. My personal preference is Chrome and it's web developer tools, but Firefox, firebug, and even Internet Explorer come with pretty good tools nowadays. Don't wait for the browser to tell you what's wrong, but use the debuggers for that.

Comment: *"Based on what I read, if they are in the same folder I should be able to just reference `<Script src="JS.js">` as there is no folder structure to look through, is that correct?"* Yes, that's correct, provided you have `</script>` after it.

Comment: The problem most likely has to do with the *contents* of the JS file.

Comment: Strongly recommend *not* using direct file access. Install a free webserver. Some things behave differently when served from a server than when you use local file URLs.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend popping open [Chrome's Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) to see where the issue may lie (and, if you're new to development, these are tools that are built into Chrome that will make your life *so* much easier).

Your assumption about not requiring a path should be correct: if you're referencing another file that lives in the same directory, omitting a full path will cause the browser to assume the path is relative (e.g. "right next to") to the current file:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Title in browser tab</title>
</head>
<body>
"Text on the page"
<script src="JS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```